# Spring JPQL for array of strings as optional parameter

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, jpql

I have created a REST API with an endpoint `GET` which should return mails matching the given criteria. All parameters of the `GET` endpoint are optional and should be concatenated by `AND`:

1. `id`: the mail's id (auto generated when creating a new mail)
2. `mail_from`: the sender of the mail
3. `received_before`: filters for mails received before a given date
4. `received_after`: filters for mails received after a given date
5. `rcpt_to`: an array the recipient's mail addresses; important is that the filtered mails should contain ALL recipients given as parameter values of `rcpt_to`

As I was not able to filter by a date range using the query creation from method names described in the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods), I created custom queries.

I implemented a query for parameters 1-4 (see method `getMailByCustomQuery`) and another query for parameter `rcpt_to` (see method `getMailByRecipient`). As the latter uses `HAVING` I cannot simply merge both queries. How can I merge both queries to have a single method/query for my `GET` endpoint? Or is there any alternative approach?

**MailRepository.java**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MailRepository extends JpaRepository<Mail, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT m FROM Mail m " +
            "WHERE (:id IS NULL OR m.id = :id) " +
            "AND (:mailFrom IS NULL OR m.mailFrom = :mailFrom)" +
            "AND ( CAST(:receivedBefore AS date) IS NULL OR m.received < :receivedBefore) " +
            "AND ( CAST(:receivedAfter AS date) IS NULL OR m.received > :receivedAfter)")
    List<Mail> getMailByCustomQuery(
            @Param("id") Long id,
            @Param("mailFrom") String mailFrom,
            @Param("receivedBefore") Date receivedBefore,
            @Param("receivedAfter") Date receivedAfter
    );

    @Query("SELECT m " +
            "FROM Mail m LEFT JOIN m.rcptTo to2 " +
            "WHERE to2 IN :rcptTo " +
            "GROUP BY m.id " +
            "HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT to2) = :rcptToLength")
    List<Mail> getMailByRecipient(
            @Param("rcptTo") List<String> rcptTo,
            @Param("rcptToLength") Long rcptToLength
    );
}
```

**MailRestController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mailStore")
public class MailRestController {
private MailRepository repository;
@Inject
public void setRepository(MailRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addMail(@RequestBody Mail mail) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.save(mail), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Collection<Mail>> getMail(
        @RequestParam(required = false) Long id,
        // Example for timestamp format: 2001-07-22T12:08:56.235-07:00
        @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX") Date received_before,
        @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX") Date received_after,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String mail_from) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.getMailByCustomQuery(id, mail_from, received_before, received_after), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Collection<Mail>> getMail(
        @RequestParam(required = false) List<String> rcpt_to) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.getMailByRecipient(rcpt_to, (long) rcpt_to.size()), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

**Mail.java** (getter and setter omitted)

```
@Entity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Mail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "received")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonProperty("received")
    private Date received;

    @JsonProperty("received_from")
    private String receivedFrom;

    @JsonProperty("received_by")
    private String receivedBy;

    @JsonProperty("mail_from")
    private String mailFrom;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private String data;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetClass = String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "rcptTo")
    @Column(name = "Value")
    @JsonProperty("rcpt_to")
    private List<String> rcptTo = new ArrayList<>();

public Mail(Date received, String receivedFrom, String receivedBy, String mailFrom,
            List<String> rcptTo, String data) {
    this.received = received;
    this.receivedFrom = receivedFrom;
    this.receivedBy = receivedBy;
    this.mailFrom = mailFrom;
    this.rcptTo = rcptTo;
    this.data = data;
}
```

Comment: Try having a look at [QueryDsl](http://www.querydsl.com/).

Comment: I came here to recommend QueryDsl also. Your use case sounds like the perfect application. Note that Spring Data also registers converters that will let you inject a QueryDsl predicate as an MVC controller argument.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It looks very promising, didn't see that it is also mentioned in section 4.8 of the Spring docs. I'll update this post with a solution after implementing it.